# When I change one date picker I want another date picker to also change vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date

I'm working in vb.net after working in access for a while. I have a report which compares 2 different time periods.

I want the previous time period to change when I alter that dates in the current period.

E.g. The defaults show current period 1/12/2022 and previous period 1/12/2021

When I change the current time period to 1/11/2022 I would like the previous period to automatically change to 1/11/2021

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks

I tried

Private Sub DTPCurrentPeriod_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DTPCurrentPeriod.ValueChanged
DTPPreviousPeriod.value = (dateadd(timeinterval.year, -1, DTPCurrentPeriod))
chkBetweenDatesFrom.Checked = True
UpdateTitle()
End Sub

Comment: [DateTime.AddYears(Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addyears?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, whenever posting code, please use the ```` ```[yourcode]``` ```` backticks to help properly format the code for better readability and to get you your help quicker.

Lastly, dr.null commented with the dateTime.addYears function which would be a appropriate approach here.

```
Private Sub DTPCurrentPeriod_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DTPCurrentPeriod.ValueChanged
    DTPPreviousPeriod.value = DTPCurrentPeriod.value.AddYears(-1)
    chkBetweenDatesFrom.Checked = True
    UpdateTitle()
End Sub
```